# Can JavaScript in Office Word Add-in Access outlook contacts?

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I am building a Office Word Add-in using JavaScript.
In a template users need to access some contact from Local contacts stored in Outlook in the local machine.
Environment is using Local Exchange server and not Office 365 or Azure.
Is this possible ? Any Office API supports this that can be called from word API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add-in APIs don't have access to any local machine's information. If the contacts are hosted on Office 365, you could use the single sign on feature available to add-ins to access the contacts through Microsoft Graph APIs. However, there is no native JavaScript API support to access local or remote Exchange servers. You'd have to write custom REST API layer that add-in could call to retrieve the contacts.